# Как сделать выдачу заявок python aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу телеграмм бот на aiogram для обработки заявок на тех обслуживание. Проблема заключается в том что хотел сделать вывод заявок админу по очереди как пример в Давинчике есть такое. Структура такова что зарегистрированный пользователь подает заявку потом админу приходит сообщение что у него есть не просмотренная заявка и количество "Новая заявка от пользователя 3". Пробовал сделать через условие но не получилось я не понял как правильно структурировать. Спасибо за ранее)

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'], state=FSMAdmin.textt)
async def textt(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    admin_id = 555555555
    global count
    count += 1
    await bot.send_message(admin_id, f'Новая заявка от пользователя {count}', reply_markup=kb_textt)
    await texttt(message, state)

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'], state=FSMAdmin.texttt)
async def texttt(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    admin_id = 555555555
    if admin_id == message.from_user.id:
        if message.text == "Посмотреть":
            cur.execute('SELECT * FROM zaivka ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1')
            rows = cur.fetchall()

            for row in rows:
                user_id = row[1]
                date_time = row[2]
                text = row[3]
                await bot.send_message(admin_id, f'{user_id}:\n{date_time}\n{text}')
            await state.finish()
            base.commit()
```

Comment: оригинальное название функций